# Is_Array Issue In Codeigniter Form Validation Callback Function

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I've the following callback function in my codeiginter form validation rule:

```
function validate_milestone($mileStones, $csrf) {
     if(is_array($mileStones)) {
            foreach ($mileStones as $value) {

            }
     }
}
```

This is the result of `var_dump`

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'Name' => string 'a' (length=1)
      'Amount' => string '50.00' (length=5)
      'Type' => string 'AMOUNT' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'Name' => string 'b' (length=1)
      'Amount' => string '20.00' (length=5)
      'Type' => string 'AMOUNT' (length=6)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'Name' => string 'c' (length=1)
      'Amount' => string '30.00' (length=5)
      'Type' => string 'AMOUNT' (length=6)
```

If I remove `if(is_array())` condition from the above code, then PHP returns a warning of "**Invalid argument supplied for foreach**". When I used `var_dump($mileStones)` it gave array type of variable. Then what is the role of this PHP condition in removing the warning?

Comment: show the var_dump result of milestones

Comment: I've updated my question. See var_dump

Answer (score 0):

When you put the [is_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) condition, the code block is simply skipped when $mileStones is not an array (which happens in some cases caused by some other portion of your code that you haven't shared here) and as a result the foreach statement is never executed and gets skipped (thus no warning):

```
if(is_array($mileStones)) {
            echo 'This entire block is skipped when $mileStones is not an array.'; 
            foreach ($mileStones as $value) {

            }
     }
```

Now when you remove the is_array() check, the foreach loop is executed no matter what and as $mileStones **is not an array or is an empty array** in some cases, the built-in warning is thrown. Try this to confirm:

```
   if (is_array($mileStones)) {
    foreach ($mileStones as $value) {

    }
} else {
    echo 'Damn, $mileStones is indeed not an array in some weird cases that I need to check now.';
}
```

**Note:** In my opinion you should not use the is_array() check as it simply ignores the situation and all the built-in error handling gets skipped - making debugging difficult.

Comment: If have used var_dump just above the foreach loop and var_dump is saying it is an array. Then why foreach loop is giving warning that's I asked.

Comment: What thing have you explained to me is I've not understood. I know what is_array does and when foreach gives warning.

Comment: What I am trying to explain would be clear to you if you just add an else statement with some text and test run your program multiple times with different conditions. You will observe that sometimes or in some cases  $mileStones won't be an array.

Comment: It is array in each and every case. How can you say, it would not be an array sometimes?

Comment: I can say that because "Invalid argument supplied for foreach" usually occurs when you don't provide an array or provide an empty array to foreach loop.